# AVD black screen with Visual Studio

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator, xamarin.android, android-virtual-device

I decided to try and create an Android app using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2015. However, when I click on Debug, the emulator opens and there is only a black screen. No Android logo or anything.

I already scavenged Stack Exchange among other sites for solutions, such as checking or unchecking `Use Host GPU`. But nothing seems to work.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6z1bw.png) is a screenshot of the configuration

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you consider trying Samsung Test Lab? every time i run an emulator it's a pain, and it's super slow, the best way i found that works for me was Samsung Lab you can test your app on a real device i think this is the best way to test apps
you can connect the device via adb using adb connect localhost:port or adb connect 127.0.0.1:port

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it out  However, could you supply me with a link please I can't seem to find it online.

Comment: You are welcome :) you have a lot of devices over ther, tablets, smartwatches and phones,  you get 20 free credit per day is 100% free 15min = 1 credit

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I was able to use one of the Samsung virtual devices but I'm still confused on how to run my application on it. How do I go about this?

Comment: You can right click, and click in Test and choose Install Aplication, you wait until the upload finishes and click install, or you can just drag and drop the apk to the phone, when the upload is complete you will get a pop up asking you if you want to install the app

Comment: Thanks I'll try that out :)